# How do you select rows based on the values of a column?

Tags: r

Probably the question is very simple, but I'm pretty new in R Studio. I have a matrix with a lot of scores of a given team. So it looks like this:

```
    H/A Goals Goals Against Goals H Goals Against H Goals A Goals Against A
[1,]   1     2             1       2               1      -1              -1
[2,]   0     0             2      -1              -1       0               2
[3,]   1     1             0       1               0      -1              -1
[4,]   0     3             2      -1              -1       3               2
[5,]   1     0             1       0               1      -1              -1
[6,]   0     1             3      -1              -1       1               3
>
```

Where in the column1 (H/A), 1 correspond for Home Games and 0 for Away games.

How could I remove the rows when there is a -1 in both column 4 and column 5? I don't want to have those rows because i want to do some maths only using home or away games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are dealing with a matrix, you have to provide column numbers (column 4 and column 5) and create a condition as an intersection of two subconditions:

```
 m <- m[m[,4] != -1 & m[,5] != -1,]
```

**Data**

```
m <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 0L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 0L, -1L, 
1L, -1L, -1L, 0L, -1L, 3L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 2L, -1L, 2L, -1L, 3L
), .Dim = 6:7, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 
"f", "g")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
old_dataframe<-data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rpois(100,1),z=rnorm(100),q=rnorm(100),l=rpois(100,1))
new_dataframe <- old_dataframe[old_dataframe[,4] > 0 & old_dataframe[,5]>0, ]
```

Comment: @gkfm23 they are just for providing minimal example or  for creating a dataset . The required code is in second line. If it serves your purpose  accept the answer